# Latin Modern too lean for printing: what font would you recommend?

Tags: fonts

The Latin Modern font is beautiful, but a bit too lean: the printer is afraid of poor inking, and the text difficult to read. I tested Erewhon, but not sure. What font you recommend? Garamond? Erewhon? Fourier?

Thanks for any advice, and happy new year!

Comment: If you like the design of Latin Modern you can try NewComputerModern. It's a variant of Latin Modern which includes a "Book" weight which is a bit heavier than Latin Modern. You can load it with `\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}`.

Comment: Mlmodern and Concrete math (concmath-otf) fonts are available as well. Mlmodern is essentially a thicker version of CM. Concrete is a thick, slab serif version of computer modern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I firmly recommend Libertinus Serif. It has the right weight for printing, and has math support. I have actually used it (for text, not math) in a print-on-demand book.

Install package `libertinus-fonts`. That gets the fonts (serif, sans, mono), but not *sty support. If you also need *.sty support for math scripting, then also install `libertinus-otf`. There is also `libertinus-math`.

You can use other fonts. EBGaramond is OK. Clara is very good, but does not have a super-large character set. Cochineal is good.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The serif font is beautiful, dense and easy to read. The sans serif bold is a bit less beautiful. But both of them do the job, thanks!